# Flask image cant upload (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Hi i coding a blog script but get FileNotFound error.
Python code:

```
@app.route('/upload',methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    title = request.form['title']
    context = request.form['text']
    author = request.form['author']
    img=request.files['img']
    path = os.path.join(app.root_path,'/images',img.filename)
    img.save(path)

    new=Posts(title=title,context=context,image=path,author=author)
    db.session.add(new)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('blog'))
```

Error:

```
img.save(path)
  File "/home/coderrpy/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3066, in save
    dst = open(dst, "wb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/images/images.jpeg'
```

I have never received such an error before, I don't know why.

Please help me

Comment: remove `/` from `/images`, keep it only `images`

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have shared, I believe you upload a image and save it in a folder,

The issues seems to be the way path is been generated, from the documentation os.path https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

> Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is
> the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly one
> directory separator following each non-empty part except the last,
> meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part
> is empty. If a component is an absolute path, all previous components
> are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path
> component.

to make this work you can define path by this way

```
 path = os.path.join(app.root_path,'/images',img.filename)
```

Also if you're uploading files via Flask, you might need to put some more steps to keep the integrity of the files This might help

https://flask-uploads.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

As [**@sahasrara62** points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089815/flask-image-cant-upload-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory#comment118587940_67089815)

You may just need to remove the preceeding `/` from `/images`, which could be tricking `.join()`

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join("/foo", "/bar")
'/bar'
>>> os.path.join("/foo", "bar")
'/foo/bar'
```

I would also recommend using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths) which should behave similarly, but is somewhat smarter about any pathing oddities you'll encounter (such as spaces and separators) by using a logical `Path` object rather than a normal string

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> pathlib.Path("/foo", "bar", "filename")
PosixPath('/foo/bar/filename')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your '/images' to './images'

```
path = os.path.join(app.root_path,'./images', img.filename)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).